# .Net Application to capture image from pda camera

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile

I need a .net application to interact with pda's camera so that with save button (in my application) I can save in sql server, with zoom button (in my application) I can zoom the image.

Answer (score 1):

mmm, at first glance your question reads like you are after an app to do this (which is why I voted to close the question as non programming related)

but...If you are in fact after the compact framework code for this then, this may help (and I'll try reverse my vote...)

```
CameraCaptureDialog cameraCapture = new CameraCaptureDialog();

cameraCapture.Owner = null;
cameraCapture.InitialDirectory = @"\My Documents";
cameraCapture.DefaultFileName = @"test.3gp";
cameraCapture.Title = "Camera Demo";
cameraCapture.VideoTypes = CameraCaptureVideoTypes.Messaging;
cameraCapture.Resolution = new Size(176, 144);
cameraCapture.VideoTimeLimit = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15);  // Limited to 15 seconds of video.
cameraCapture.Mode = CameraCaptureMode.VideoWithAudio;

if (DialogResult.OK == cameraCapture.ShowDialog())
{
    Console.WriteLine("The picture or video has been successfully captured to:\n{0}", cameraCapture.FileName);
}
```

This code snipped from the [MSDN article on the CameraCaptureDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.forms.cameracapturedialog.showdialog.aspx)